# Confusions about Galois theory and the quintic

Tags: galois-theory

I am very confused about Galois theory, because I have never seen a rigorous presentation of it. In particular, I don't understand what the books mean by "radical expression". It is also not clear whether we are working in the real domain or the complex domain. Related to this, I do not know if the root functions are genuine functions, patial functions, or multivalued functions. And if they are multivalued functions, how can we form terms based on them? Anyway, can someone help to clarify this, or perhaps point me to a book where this is all done more rigorously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A book recommendation would depend on your background. But the book: [Galois Theory by Ian Stewart](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584883936) is a great book on Galois Theory and the quintic. It defines exactly what, for example, radical expression means.

The basic idea is: We are considering polynomials with real number coefficients and we want to know about real roots. For polynomials of degree less than or equal to $4$ you can find a formula that will give you the roots to such a polynomial. That is, each root can be expressed using addition, subtraction, division, multiplication, and taking $n$th roots. That's it.

Now, it is possible to find a concrete polynomial of degree $5$ that has a root that cannot be expressed in this way.

Comment: Yeh but I'd recommend the first or second edition. The third edition is entirely different. Or if you really only care about field extensions over the rationals, the third edition is fine to read in the order it's presented.

Comment: And more specifically we're considering algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, so not any real coefficients will do, since $\mathbb R$ has transcendental elements